# Bayesian Updating with Conditional Independence of two tests

Tags: bayesian, bayes-theorem

I have the following scenario of Bayes updating with which I struggle quite a bit.

Imagine we are interested in the probability that a given person has a disease $D$. We perform two different tests $T_1,T_2$ on a blood sample of this person.

Im interested in something like the probability that a person has the disease given both tests return positive.

$P(D|T_1 =1, T_2 = 1) = \frac{P(T_1 =1, T_2 = 1|D) * P(D)}{P(T_1 =1, T_2 = 1)}$

Importantly, both tests are not independent (as they both depend on the blood sample), but given some blood-based measure $x$, we assume conditional independence.

**My first question is:** How do I correctly incorporate the conditional independence assumption into the equation? Is it simply:

$P([D|T_1 =1, T_2 = 1]|x) = \frac{[P(T_1 =1, T_2 = 1|D]|x) * P(D|x)}{P([T_1 =1, T_2 = 1]|x)}$

?

Furthermore, I have a scenario in mind in which I can reasonably guess how the tests translate $x$ into a probability of having a disease e.g., $p_1(x) = 0.2 + x, p_2(x) = 0.3 + x$, but Im also not sure how to properly incorporate this information into the equation.

I appreciate any tips how to proceed, thank you!

Best
N

Comment: Your conditional independence assumption suggests $P(T_1=t_1,T_2=t_2 \mid D=d)=P(T_1=t_1 \mid D=d)P(T_2=t_2 \mid D=d)$ for all $t_1,t_2,d$

Comment: But shouldn't this be only true conditional on some level of $x$? I'm curious what Bayes Rule then eventually looks like.

Comment: You have not told use the relationship between $D$ and $x$ but I suppose they are essentially the disease or a measure of it.

Comment: Let's say $x$ is the amount of oxygen in your blood, which indicates the disease but is not the disease itself. How each test translates oxygen into a probability of having the disease differs between both tests, but they both only use the amount of oxygen as an input.